# Parse CodeIgniter cookie with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to parse a CodeIgniter cookie with node.js. I'm using this code to get all the cookies:

```
function parse_cookies(_cookies) {
   var cookies = {};

   _cookies && _cookies.split(';').forEach(function( cookie ) {
     var parts = cookie.split('=');
     cookies[ parts[ 0 ].trim() ] = ( parts[ 1 ] || '' ).trim();
   });

   return cookies;
}
```

It returns all the cookies so then I do:

```
var cookies = parse_cookies(handshakeData.headers.cookie);
console.log(cookies.ci_session);
```

But the ci_session cookie is in this format:

```
a:4:{s:10:"session_id";s:32:"152933dbf8a52a55b48518b940451aey";s:10:"ip_address";s:12:"192.168.1.68";s:10:"user_agent";s:72:"Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:34.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/34.0";s:13:"last_activity";i:1419314157;}44503444ab1688f1e3a5ece6a3ff1e024e4b773f
```

How can I get the session_id value from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This format looks like PHP's [`serialize()`](http://devdocs.io/php/function.serialize) function. There's an **[NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-unserialize)** to parse those.

If you don't want to add another dependency, and assuming CodeIgniter's cookie scheme won't change much, you can do something as simple as

```
cookies.ci_session.match(/s:32:"([a-z0-9]{32})"/)[1]
```

Which finds the occurrence of `s:32:"(??)"` where ?? is 32 alphanumeric characters. The `[1]` is because `match()` returns an array of matches, `[0]` is the entire match (`s:32:"(??)"`) and `[1]` is the first capture group (enclosed in brackets), namely `??`, which is what you want.